# how to custom sort in spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

for a column like

```
col
a
b
c
```

how do I get the output

```
col
c
a
b
```

is there an equivalent of order by field() in sqark sql?

Comment: `select col from table order by col desc`?

Comment: @mck "custom" order

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought I saw col, c, b, a...

Answer (score 0):

There is no logic behind your sort order from my perspective. If you have one then you need to write a function where you can provide an "order mechanism". For example create an ordered list of all your possible values and then map this list to a key value. c=1, a=2, b=3. Then add a column with the key values to the Dataframe and order on the new column.